# All paths down on vSphere esxi 5.1, LSI 9211-8i

Tags: vmware-esxi, intel, lsi

Works 100%
    ESXi 5.1

> HBA (LSI 1064e)   > 1x SAS2 100GB SSD

Doesn't work
    ESXi 5.1

> HBA (LSI 9211-8i IT /IBM M1015)   > 1x SAS2 100GB SSD

After a few hours of heavy HD load i get:
 - Device or filesystem with identifier ['**all drives'**] has entered the All Paths Down state. 
 - ESXi retries but loses connectivity to the SAS drive, marks it as "dead or error"
 - reboot fixes the issue

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using the 9211i as an HBA or as a RAID controller?

Comment: HBA, 2x SATA2 2TB (RDM), 100GB SAS (esxi datastore)

Comment: Did you update the firmware on your LSI controller?

Comment: yes, P14 IR firmware (does IT also)

Answer (score 1):

Update the ESXis LSI 9211-8i driver.
VMWare is shipping v.10 and we are at v.14.
This update resolved a lot of issues for me.